# GLSL - changing to vec3 colors

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glsl, shader, openframeworks

I am very new at at shaders and have been trying to figure this out for hours... I found a shader on glslsandbox that draws a simple grid. I am trying to understand how I can change the colors of the grid from one decimal to a vec3 color.

```
float x = gl_FragCoord.x - gl_FragCoord.y;
float y = gl_FragCoord.y + gl_FragCoord.x;
bool grid = mod(x, CELL_SIZE) < LINE_WIDTH || mod(x, CELL_SIZE) < LINE_WIDTH;
float color = grid ? 1.0 : 0.0; 
gl_FragColor = vec4( vec3( color ), 0.2 );
```

The line I need to change is

```
float color = grid ? 1.0 : 0.0;
```

which only allows me to use black, white and grey. Any thoughts on how I can change both colors to vec3?

Comment: `lowp vec3 color = grid ? vec3(0.0):vec3(1.0)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like below should work though I havent tested it:

```
lowp vec3 gridColor = vec3(0.5,0.5,0.0);
lowp vec3 nonGridColor = vec3(0.5,0.0,0.5);
vec3 colorv = grid ? gridColor : nonGridColor;
gl_FragColor = vec4( colorv, 0.2 );
```

Comment: you missed a precision qualifier on the 3rd vec3 ;)

Comment: Works perfectly thank you! Quick question is there any reason you used lowp specifically instead of high or med?

Comment: well you're only using values to one decimal place, so you don't need high precision at all. There's no hard defined precision range for the qualifiers, it depends on the specific implementation. Using lower precision can improve performance in some cases, so it's best to use them wherever you can, although you may need higher precision for more detailed renders.

Comment: Makes great sense. Thanks @originaluser2